# using System.out.println to debug in JavaServlet in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to debug my Java servlet code in Tomcat with `System.out.println`.

Where will the output go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They'll be in `catalina.out` or one of the `localhost*.log` files in your Tomcat's `logs` directory assuming no other logging configuration/libraries. If you're using any third party libraries it's unlikely they'd also use simple `println`s, however.

Is there a specific reason you're not using a logging framework or the standard Java logging? It's quite a bit more useful, and configurable.